# How do I pass a parameter containing backslash in Python cx_oracle call_proc

Tags: python, cx-oracle

while using the cx_oracle package in python, I need a to pass a parameter that has a backslash(`\`) when using `callproc`, please see the example below:

```
cursor.callproc("procedure_name",['C:\desktop\','xyz.xlsx']
```

I am getting an error because of the `\`  in the parameter. Could you advise me on what I need to do?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? And is this something you've hardcoded into the script or is it based on user input?

Comment: Make sure you mark an answer as correct if it helped so that people looking at this in the future will know what helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a raw string, use double backslashes, or use forwards backslashes:

```
cursor.callproc("procedure_name", [r'C:\desktop\','xyz.xlsx'])
cursor.callproc("procedure_name", ['C:\\desktop\\','xyz.xlsx'])
cursor.callproc("procedure_name", ['C:/desktop/','xyz.xlsx'])
```

Python can normally adapt forwards and backwards slashes to the `OS`, although I'm not 100% sure on whether `cx_Oracle` will allow it. If that doesn't work, one of the other two should work.

Comment: Thank you, the  double backslash helped